# What layout is good for this Java UI?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

To be precise, I am trying to build UI for *Newton's forward difference* table using JFrame.
[image: **Newton Forward Difference table**]

Is it worth creating gridlayout of 8 x 8 labels and (array of) textfields like this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewtonFwd ssf = new NewtonFwd();
    ssf.setVisible(true);
    ssf.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8, 2, 2));
    ssf.setSize(1400, 600);

}

public NewtonFwd() {
    Container c = getContentPane();
    JTextField[] xfields = new JTextField[6];       
    ...
    JTextField[] ydfields4 = new JTextField[2];
    c.add(new JLabel("x values"));
    c.add(new JLabel("y values"));
    // and so on...
```

(Full code at https://pastebin.com/WbqZ7HFu)

What am I missing?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: `GridBagLayout`

Comment: The "basic" answer to your question is, "the one that works" - You need to explore some of the basic functionality and decide which one(s) are going to meet your needs

Comment: How about a `JTable` ?

Comment: what I am asking is what layout is good to design such UI? how do I design it?  I am a new programmer and didn't find any helpful guide elsewhere.